# can't hide elements on mobile using modernizr

Tags: modernizr

I was digging around but couldn't find the answer. Does anyone know the classes that Modernizr adds to the `html` tag? I want to hide a div on mobile devices.

I want to target it via CSS but i can't find the class to target the devices using modernizr

Comment: One way is `.touch` vs. `.no-touch`.  That obviously doesn't *exactly* match "mobile", though.  Usually for that, you would want to just use media queries.  What is your use case?  No classes are added to determine mobile vs. desktop, though.

Comment: I want to hide a pop up on mobile (handhelds) but have it pop up on a desktop.  @Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CSS features](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css), [HTML5 features](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5), and [misc. features](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-misc) that Modernizr detects, there is no mobile feature.  I guess that would have to rely on a UserAgent string, which is not a smart idea.  The whole point of Modernizr is to detect certain feature sets, which you can use to determine whether or not a feature of yours would work (for example, oh this browser doesn't have inline-svg so don't display this SVG; instead of, oh we think this is IE8 so let's not show this SVG).

I've come across multiple scenarios where my modals (pop ups) don't play nicely on small mobile / touch devices.  In that case, I've always done something like this:

```
<a href="/register">Register</a>

<script>
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        if(!Modernizr.touch) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // show register modal
        }

        // fallback to page
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What if the 'pop up' launches on `dom ready` how will i go about writing something like that? @sam

Comment: Just to hide it on mobile.

Comment: You could do the same thing on DOM ready, the `Modernizr.touch` conditional is the important part. That will only hide on touch, which is not necessarily mobile.